# Wordpress Settings api data not sanitized if i use ajax

Tags: ajax, settings-api

I have a phone number field on admin page that i have created using settings API. I have specified a sanitization function that removes everthing from the input except for numbers. Now if i submit the data by clicking the submit button data is sanitized properly but if a try to do this using ajax post request it does not sanitize the data but saves the unsanitized data in the

```
jQuery( '#theme_phone_save' ).click( function( e ) {

var formData = jQuery( "#theme_form_phone" ).serializeArray();

jQuery.post('options.php', formData, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log( data );
});
    e.preventDefault();
} );
```

How do i sanitize the form data submitted using ajax?